# Chat account suspended?

Tags: support, chat

My chat account has just been suspended for 30 days.

- I have not had any lasting suspensions over 30 minutes in the past month.
- There was completely no warning about it.
- I do not think I posted anything too controversial, off-topic, or NSFW.
- I had not sent a message for a while.

Can someone please link me to the offending message? Is there a way to shorten this suspension?

Comment: Yeah I got one week. I actually needed Dennis's help about a TIO thing. I just pinged Martin

Comment: @Christopher There are several ways to contact me about TIO that bypass SE, all of which can be found [here](https://tio.run/nexus#community).

Answer (score 17):

- > I have not had any suspensions over 30 minutes in the past month.

  This isn't true.
- > There was completely no warning about it.

  You were reminded of our rules and guidelines on multiple occasions, and occasionally kicked. Several messages of yours were moved to trash. You chose to ignore those warnings.
- > I do not think I posted anything too controversial, off-topic, or NSFW.

  This is also not true. Hence the 30-minute suspensions and kicks.

> Can someone please link me to the offending message?

You weren't suspended for a particular message. I can't link you to all of them.

Long-term suspensions are rarely handed out because of a single message. However, you constantly succeed in lowering the signal-to-noise ratio. You have been told several times that this isn't acceptable in TNB, but we've failed to see any improvements in your behavior since your last suspension. The latest example is probably your nonsensical conversation from today that resulted in a lot of random users getting pinged.

> Is there a way to shorten this suspension?

No.

Comment: I think the 1 week suspension was manually removed by Mego.

Comment: The conversation that involved pinging multiple people was not entirely initiated by me, and only one of the pings was mine.

Comment: Mego isn't a mod and thus cannot remove suspensions. Even if we don't count that one, you've still had suspensions in the past month. -- I'm aware that you can't be blamed entirely for that conversation, but it was just the last drop, not the entire reason you got suspended.

Comment: I guess the main shock was getting a 30 day ban that was to me completely out of the blue. I wasn't aware that these comparatively small incidents caused such a large issue. Most of the time I assumed that the kick/suspension was a discrete response to one specific action. I just didn't realize that they were building up like this.

Comment: I know the suspension was removed by someone, seeing that I first saw a one week suspension notice and then the page reloaded with it removed.

Comment: I know that it was removed by someone. I'm telling you that it wasn't the only one. And 30 days is the default duration after a 7 day suspension.

Comment: I guess the automatic duration increase doesn't reset after a suspension gets removed. Theoretically, if that suspension never happened, would this one be 7 days long?

Comment: Yes, most likely.

Comment: @Dennis I did actually need your help. I wanted to know what the header and footer did for TIO. I only pinged Martin For no reason (yes I understand that is bad now) also if you counted pinging ATaco I was replying to what he said while he was in the room.

Comment: "[...] but it was just the last drop, not the entire reason you got suspended"

Comment: @Christopher If someone is using language you truly find offensive, you should flag it when you see it. If you're only finding it offensive now that you're angry about being suspended, well...

Comment: @Geobits I have actually flagged before. I am not angry about being suspended mostly bothered by inconsistency in the enforcement

Comment: @Christopher Most of what I told Mendeleev applies to you as well. You weren't suspended for this particular "conversation" (but, to get the facts straight, you alone pinged Martin, Helka, and me), but because your behavior in The Nineteenth Byte over the past months isn't acceptable. The elevated number of times you have been kicked, chat-suspended for 30-minute periods, and have had your chat post moved to the Trash room serve both as evidence and warnings.

Comment: @Christopher I won't take part in the *but X did Y, which is **way** worse* discussion because it isn't constructive, but if you truly think that there is too much swearing in The Nineteenth Byte, please feel free to flag the offending posts (be aware that your flags may get declined) or open another meta discussion about it. If you choose the latter option, I encourage you to not mention your suspension, as the two topics are unrelated and should be treated as such.

Comment: @Dennis Ok Yeah I was confused yesterday :P. I will just wait it out

Comment: @Dennis actually I have a question. I do not believe I have been kicked or suspended in the last month (not counting now). But chat-suspended has happened I think  3 times (I am not counting the one that I was suspended for a minute and didn't know as I had left and posted "noise" (not suspend worthy on its own and got suspended again). I also don't remember getting kicked much. Can you share numbers with me?

Comment: @Christopher We usually don't make this public, but since you asked, I guess it is OK. You had 30-minute on Feb 23, Mar 20, and Mar 31. You were kicked on Jan 23, Feb 27 (twice), Mar 7, Mar 15, and Apr 26.

Comment: @Dennis thanks. You should expect the numbers from now on to stay the same. I will try extra hard to be good. Also I contacted you on the gitter with my question