# Very long chat suspension for harmless joke

Tags: support, chat

As usual, I was going about my day, occasionally stopping by SE chat. I replied to [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38735177#38735177) by [@cairdcoinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) ("I really need to stop clicking on every link that is posted") with [this other message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38735205#38735205) ("@cairdcoinheringaahing [Try this one](https://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)") as a joke. The link was a rickroll.

I was promptly and deservedly kicked from the chatroom by @DJMcMayhem, and the messages were moved to trash. There was a small amount of discussion about them. I thought the discussion was over. I returned to writing a website in Rails.

However, when I returned to the chatroom, I found this:

[image: Image of 364 day suspension]

...

I was shocked.

Can anyone please offer an explanation?

(Note: This prevents me from chatting in any room, not just TNB.)

---

E: Not a dupe of my other question, the context and situation is very different

Comment: This is a dupe of your other question. Just like last time, you were being obnoxious in chat, and a moderator chose to suspend you for not learning from the previous times.

Comment: Don't you think that Dennis answering your question with the exact same answer as the other question means that it's a duplicate?

Answer (score 14):

[We've been over this before.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12219/12012)

Long-term suspensions are rarely handed out because of a single message. However, you constantly succeed in lowering the signal-to-noise ratio. You have been told several times that this isn't acceptable in The Nineteenth Byte.

We've failed to see any improvements in your behavior since your last suspension. The large amount of kicks you received since then should have served as a warning.

Comment: That's considered a large amount? It isn't much more than the frequency of kicks in other internet communities I'm in... hmmm... maybe I should rethink my approach to conversation

Comment: Shouldn't just a few kicks already be enough for you to rethink your behaviour?